# i want to display top 3 highest paid employees form each department

Tags: sql, hive

[image]

image contains sal table
and i want to display top 3 highest salary paid employees in each department in hive

Comment: What happens when there are multiple employees tied in third place? You want them all, or just one *randomly*?

Comment: In the future, post sample data, code etc as text and not as images

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the database or version of it, so I'll assume it's a modern one that supports window functions. You can use the `RANK()` window function as shown below:

```
select * 
from (
  select *,
    rank() over(partition by deptid order by sal desc) as rk
  from sal
) x
where rk <= 3
```